# .eslintrc.js file rules being ignored

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

My rules for @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises and @typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises specifically are not being obeyed, I have them set to off, yet they are still being emitted

[rules and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hdw2.png)

I've tried clearing the cache, adjusting other options, and other clients

Comment: check in the output of `eslint` where is the config loaded from, is it actually loaded using this `.eslintrc.js`config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the top line (3) pictured, it likely that the rules are being enabled in *`overrides`*. See [Configuration Files - ESLint > How to overrides work?](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files#how-do-overrides-work). You'll want to add the `"off"` settings inside the `overrides` that enabled them.

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  overrides: {
    extends: ["@typescript-eslint/recommended-type-checked"],
    files: ["**/*.ts"],
    rules: {
      "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": "off",
    },
  },
  // ...
};
```

Aside: it's hard to answer definitively because you're only showing part of the ESLint configuration file. In general, it's best to post your entire ESLint config when asking for help with it.

Comment: Yeah looks like they were overridden by a different file I wasn't aware of